# The best way to parse str to float in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, parsing, casting

I got a money values columns erroneously displayed as string:

[money value as string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaVad.png)

I've tried to parse that column applying usual methods, unsuccessfully:

[astype(float) and pd.to_numeric(df.col, errors=['coerce'])](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryhp6.png)

Finally, I can only win if I use string manipulation techniques. As you see, too verbose:

[apply split casting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/venOH.png)

So, what's happened here? There's no graceful way to solve this parsing?

ps: using `pd.read_csv(path, dtype={'receita': float}` I also got wrong

Comment: Nice if "," is thousand separator. In my case it's decimal sep. The value 10,681.01 changes to 106,811.00 ... thx to reply

Comment: remove the comma then convert it into float. If you want in comma format you can use any third party library afterwards